# How to android google map at center while zooming by double tapping or pinch

Tags: android, google-maps, pinchzoom

When I zoom the map by double tapping or pinch, currently center point gets changed.

I want to keep map center point at its position while zooming.

I have tried OnCameraChageListener but It gets called regularly,

```
LatLngBounds bounds =
             googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
             googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,
             mapLayout.getWidth(), mapLayout.getHeight(), 0));
```

Map gets stuck. So its not correct way

anybody has solution for it?

Comment: did you find a solution yet on this Aniket ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
CameraUpdate center=CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

googleMap.moveCamera(center);
googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);
```

Comment: After Set Map Fragment Or Marker

Comment: googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

   markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(
     new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello OneRaj");
   markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
     .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
   googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

After This